# x86 - Push 8 bit value to stack

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-16

Is it possible to push an 8 bit value to the stack? NASM gives an error when I try to push AL to the stack; later, I found out that was because the stack holds 16-bit values. What would the correct method of pushing an 8-bit value to the stack be?

(This is for the 8086)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot push an 8 bit value on the stack.  The most sensible way is to just push the corresponding 16 bit register on the stack:

```
push ax
```

Note that this pushes one byte of junk in `ah` in addition to the one byte you wanted to write, but that should be no problem.